# How to download .bib of all papers ever published in main venues in TCS (journals, conferences, repositories, etc.)

Tags: bibliography

Is there now a system out there that does this?  Or even venue by venue -- for example, is there a way to download all references for all papers published any time in JACM?  I tried DBLP but I couldn't find a simple way to do that.  (Ideally, I'd like references without "cross-ref".)

Comment: I don't know. But your asking has definitely piqued my interest as to Why?